# smooth scrolling not working

Tags: jquery

im trying to scroll the window when a certain divs are clicked,the problem i have got is it works perfectly in safari but in IE 6 and above there seems to be flickering.The screen also flickers when you try clicking in the scroll area of the window !! I cant figure out what the problem is.Could some one help please?

Jquery Code :

```
              $("div.trigger").click(function(){
   $('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $(this).next(".toggle_container").offset().top
   }, 2000);

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [jQuery Easing Plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) in order to deal with that.

Comment: sorry im a bit confused,i know the easing will do the job but how do i scroll to that position ?

Comment: @manraj: There are such problems when you are not sure about the exact issue. Why not use the ScrollTo plugin instead: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo

Answer (score 0):

The problem IS Ie6